# Sequelize-cli how to create seed files from an existing database?

Tags: node.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

### Issue:

In order to start in a clean environment for developing stuff for a web app I would appreciate to be able to retrieve some data from an existing DB (let say the 10 first lines of every tables) in order to create a sequelize seed file per table. It will then be possible to seed an empty DB with these data into the corresponding models and migrations.

I have found the tool named `sequelize-auto` which seems to work fine to generate a model file from an exsting DB (beware of not already having for example a uses.js model ; it will be overwritten !) : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto.

This tool will create a model file, but neither a migration or a seed file.

### Question:

Is there a way to build a seed file from an existing database?

Comment: did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Found this cool module
you can create (dump) seed with command

```
npx sequeliseed generate table_name --config
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequeliseed

Comment: fyi : I'couldn succeded somehow 
getting errors

relation "tablename" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You may find some library to do this job, but in my situation, the use case was to insert data from the user interface and then generate the seed for it (instead of doing it one by one by hand).
So, I've prepared a custom script for it.

The script parses your SQL dump and generates Sequelize seed files. All you need to do is paste the generated SQL dump from your database (in this example, it was generated using pgAdmin4), save it as `dump.sql`, and then run the `main.py`. The `output` should be located in the folder with the same name.

[image: Edit 50069724/how-to-add-multiple-material-ui-palette-colors]

> This script was tested to work just for the output from pgAdmin4 (Right Click > Backup).